# make flex item 90% wide

Tags: css, flexbox

This is a simple question. I must be just missing the answer. I have a flex container with one flex item in it. I want the flex item to be 90% wide and centered vertically and horizontally. I just can't get it to be 90% wide. I am puzzled. Here's my code:

```
<div class="" id="popupContainer">
    <div class="flex-item-popup" id="popup">

    </div>
</div>

    #popupContainer {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display:flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: center;
    align-content: flex-start;
    align-items: center;
}
#popup {
    width: 90%;
    height: 90%;
    flex-grow: 1;
    flex-shrink: 0;
    flex-basis: 200px;
    justify-content: center;    
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: -moz-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-flex-align: center;
    -ms-flex-align: center;
    -webkit-align-items: center;
    align-items: center;
    background-color: black;
    justify-content: center; /* align horizontal */
    align-items: center; /* align vertical */
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just delete these two and it will work proprely :

```
flex-grow: 1; flex-basis: 200px;
```

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/hocdykuf/3/)**

Comment: Very good find. Thank you so much !